# How do I construct a thin controller with a dependent service?

Tags: 8

For the first time I am trying to architect a reasonably complex Drupal 8 module, and not sure of best practice for the controller.

- I need to route paths to a controller.
- I intend the controller to be
  thin (very little logic, doesn't need to testable)
- Heavy lifting will be via service class/es configured and defined by the module.

Extending *ControllerBase* should be the right path for a thin controller, however when I look in Core at the moment I notice a number of controllers that both *extend ControllerBase* and implement *ContainerInjectionInterface*. I would only implement ContainerInjectionInterface to be able to inject a different container for testing, not just selection of service in the *create* method, but Core is still in flux and I am not sure exactly why they are doing this.

I feel that I should extend *ControllerBase*, add a __construct that fetches the container and pulls in the non-standard service/s that I require via *$this->container()->get()* and indeed that does work. I also don't need the create method required to implement *ContainerInjectionInterface*.

Am I correct? I know I will need to go through a few iterations of getting the services right but want to get THIS bit right from the start and understand why I am doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this context, I have more context with the Symfony components rather than Drupal. With that said, I don't understand why you'd create a special container solution with __construct rather than just implement ContainerInjectionInterface.

Comment: Because with only extending controllerBase I can access the container provided in my __construct function to get the instance of my service (a bunch of standard services are automatically available but not my non-standard one).

Comment: Sorry editing on a tablet, this is extension of above comment. If I implement ContainerInjection interface I have to add a create method to pull desired services from an injected controller, AND a construct method to receive them as parameters, rather long winded.

Comment: ControllerBase::container() is being removed shortly. Do not rely on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ContainerInjectionInterface is used as a part of a [static factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#PHP_2).

This way, a class's constructor can specify all of the services it needs, and its factory method, in this case `create()`, can satisfy the constructor by retrieving services from the container.

The instantiated controller should never have its own copy of the container, if at all avoidable.

A brief example:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\book\Controller;

use Drupal\book\BookManager;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class BookController extends ControllerBase implements ContainerInjectionInterface {
  protected $bookManager;

  public function __construct(BookManager $bookManager) {
    $this->bookManager = $bookManager;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('book.manager')
    );
  }

  public function bookRender() {
    $book_list = array();
    foreach ($this->bookManager->getAllBooks() as $book) {
      $book_list[] = l($book['title'], $book['href'], $book['options']);
    }
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'item_list',
      '#items' => $book_list,
    );
  }
}
```

This would be declared as a controller in a routing file like this:

`_content: \Drupal\book\Controller\BookController::bookRender`

Comment: Removing container from ControllerBase that is food for thought, feels like many contrib devs will start with this class and then get stuck when they need to access non-standard services. ControllerBase was touted as lighter way to make a controller but begins to look like a dead end.

Comment: You would use ContainerInjectionInterface for any non-standard services. ControllerBase is just to get you started with the common services.