# "Drupal calls should be avoided in classes, use dependency injection instead"

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

In my module using below code for getting url alias of given url:

```
$alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias($_POST['url']);
```

But one I run Automated Review(http://pareview.sh/) in my module I am getting below warning:

> 16 | WARNING | \Drupal calls should be avoided in classes, use dependency injection instead

How can I update above code using dependency injection? My entire class code is given below.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * MyModule Class defines ajax callback function.
 */
class MyModule extends ControllerBase {
/**
 * Callback function for ajax request.
 */

  public function getUserContent() {
    $alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias($_POST['url']);
    $alias = explode('/', $alias);
    $my_module_views = views_embed_view('my_module', 'default', $alias[2]);
    $my_module= drupal_render($my_module_views);
    return array(
      '#name' => 'my_module_content',
      '#markup' => '<div class="my_module_content">' . $my_module. '</div>',
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is best practice to construct a thin Controller with a dependent service](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94227/what-is-best-practice-to-construct-a-thin-controller-with-a-dependent-service)

Comment: The other question doesn't expressly say how to avoid the error the OP is showing here. It's rather a question made from a user who wants a confirm about his plan.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take the [`BlockLibraryController`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21src%21Controller%21BlockLibraryController.php/class/BlockLibraryController/8.2.x) class as example; it extends the same class as your controller.

You define:

- A static and public [`create()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21src%21Controller%21BlockLibraryController.php/function/BlockLibraryController%3A%3Acreate/8.2.x) method that gets the values from the dependency container, and creates a new object of your class
- A [class constructor](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21src%21Controller%21BlockLibraryController.php/function/BlockLibraryController%3A%3A__construct/8.2.x) that saves the values passed from the previous method in object properties
- A set of object properties to save the values passed in the class constructor

In your case, the code would be similar to the following one.

```
class MyModuleController extends ControllerBase {
  /**
   * The path alias manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManagerInterface
   */
  protected aliasManager;

  /**
   * Constructs a MyModuleController object.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManagerInterface $alias_manager
   *   The path alias manager.
   */
  public function __construct(AliasManagerInterface $alias_manager) {
    $this->aliasManager = $alias_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('path.alias_manager')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getUserContent() {
    $alias = $this->aliasManager->getPathByAlias($_POST['url']);
    // Omissis.
  }

}
```

Don't forget to put `use \Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManagerInterface;` on the top of the file containing the code you are showing.

As side note, the code you use to render the view is wrong: You don't need to use `drupal_render()` because [`views_embed_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.module/function/views_embed_view/8.2.x) already returns a renderable array.
Then, the render array you are returning is probably not giving the output you expect. #name is probably not going to be used from Drupal, and #markup filters the markup you are passing to it, as described on [Render API overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.2.x).

> - **#markup**: Specifies that the array provides HTML markup directly. Unless the markup is very simple, such as an explanation in a paragraph tag, it is normally preferable to use #theme or #type instead, so that the theme can customize the markup. Note that the value is passed through [`\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::filterAdmin()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.php/function/Xss%3A%3AfilterAdmin/8.2.x), which strips known XSS vectors while allowing a permissive list of HTML tags that are not XSS vectors. (I.e, `<script>` and `<style>` are not allowed.) See `\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::$adminTags` for the list of tags that will be allowed. If your markup needs any of the tags that are not in this whitelist, then you can implement a theme hook and template file and/or an asset library. Alternatively, you can use the render array key #allowed_tags to alter which tags are filtered.
> - **#allowed_tags**: If #markup is supplied this can be used to change which tags are using to filter the markup. The value should be an array of tags that `Xss::filter()` would accept. If #plain_text is set this value is ignored.

Comment: This helps me a lot. Dependency injection working fine. :) Thank you.

Comment: **views_embed_view()** only providing an array. Without using **drupal_render()** how can I display it as html content?

Comment: It returns a renderable array, which can be returned from the controller method that renders a page.

Comment: Just return what `views_embed_view()` returns.

Comment: my controller is using for a ajax call. the returned content will update in the page dynamically. While return the result of `views_embed_view()` it showing `Array`

Comment: It doesn't change; between what you are returning now, and returning the result of `views_embed_view()`, it is better the latter. See also what I said about #markup being filtered.

Comment: Can we do it by the same way we used for path alias? By implementing `use Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer;` class?

Comment: In my code I have replaced `$my_module` with `$my_module_views`. I am getting text `Array`

Comment: No, there is no need to do that. You don't need the renderer, but just to return a renderable array, which is what your code does (in the wrong way) and what `views_embed_view()` does.

Comment: ok. Understood. When I am returning `views_embed_view()` result, in frontend I am getting the entire html, means page header footer and everything. I just want to display result of the view only. Fine, I updated my code in my js file extract the required data from response. Now my code looks more clean. Thanks for your correction :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to utilize dependency injection, your class needs to implement `ContainerInjectionInterface` interface. `ContainerInjectionInterface` mandates that implementing class has to have `create()` method. With additional class constructor which accepts the injected dependencies, `create()` method returns an instance of your class by passing the defined instances of dependencies to your class.

**Update:** It was rightfully pointed by @kiamlaluno that `ContainerInjectionInterface` is not required in this case since `ControllerBase` already implements it.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * MyModule Class defines ajax callback function.
 */
class MyModule extends ControllerBase {

  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManagerInterface $aliasManager */
  protected $aliasManager;

  /**
   * MyModule constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManagerInterface $alias_manager
   */
  public function __construct(AliasManagerInterface $alias_manager) {
    $this->aliasManager = $alias_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('path.alias_manager')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Callback function for ajax request.
   */
  public function getUserContent() {
    $alias = $this->aliasManager->getPathByAlias($_POST['url']);
    // Your code.
  }

}
```

Comment: It is enough you extend `ControllerBase`; it is not necessary to implement `ContainerInjectionInterface` since that is already done from `ControllerBase`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, that is correct. your code works perfect.