# How do I use dependency injection on \Drupal::moduleHandler() to a Controller?

Tags: 8, services, dependency-injection

I am using the following line in a controller class.

```
    \Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter('mymodule_myfunction', $plugin_items);
```

Pareview.sh is giving me this error message.

> \Drupal calls should be avoided in classes, use dependency injection instead.

How should I accomplish this? Do I need to create a constructor, create a method, or a service? If so, what code should the service need? I found an example on ["Drupal calls should be avoided in classes, use dependency injection instead"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207151) for a case where a service already exists.

Comment: `create` will overload the parent method - here you can inject the services you need. The constructor will then let you assign those to instance variables in the class, so you can use `$this->fooInjectedClass->methodName()`

Comment: Do we already have a question about this?  If not, we should really make this a canonical.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In a controller you inject services by using the service container. For example `ModuleHandler`:

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandlerInterface;

class MyController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * The module handler service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandlerInterface
   */
  protected $moduleHandler;

  /**
   * Constructs a MyController object
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandlerInterface $module_handler
   *   The module handler service.
   */
  public function __construct(ModuleHandlerInterface $module_handler) {
    $this->moduleHandler = $module_handler;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('module_handler')
    );  
  }
```

Then you can avoid `\Drupal` calls by using the injected service:

```
$this->moduleHandler->alter('mymodule_myfunction', $plugin_items);
```

You can inject any service, existing ones from core/contrib or services you've defined in custom code in a `*.services.yml` file.

To find a core service name I usually look into `core.services.yml`, because that's the quickest way when you are working on a drupal project in your IDE.

You can use [Drupal Console](https://drupalconsole.com/) to list all services, not only from core:

```
drupal debug:container
```

You can also use the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel), which allows you to search for a name:

```
/devel/container/service
```

Comment: This sort of question/answer should be expanded upon I agree, and contributed back to drupal.org docs. There is _some_ there, but I feel real world examples like this always help.

Comment: The `ControllerBase` class already implements the `ContainerInjectionInterface` interface. There is no need to add `implements ContainerInjectionInterface` to a class that extends `ControllerBase`.

Comment: Right, just noticed the same thing as @kiamlaluno; would be grand to update the answer!