# Use services in controller

Tags: 8

I am trying to create a custom service and call it from a controller that is being used on a route.
I use simple code, so I think I am missing something

The membership service: 
https://gist.github.com/betz/6e0cb7ce2712793711d4c9ed99a3a697

Controller:
https://gist.github.com/betz/a9aa9db636cd9b9bffea3b4e255fb1df

services file:
https://gist.github.com/betz/25aeb579c265bfba83a0e891aa883bf8

routing file:
https://gist.github.com/betz/577a411a8ede77ecc0be614044ec1a44

The error I get:

> RuntimeException: Controller
>   "Drupal\hsbxl_members\Controller\Test::test()" requires that you
>   provide a value for the "$container" argument (because there is no
>   default value or because there is a non optional argument after this
>   one). in Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerResolver->doGetArguments()
>   (line 165 of
>   /var/www/drupalvm/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/ControllerResolver.php).

So it seems the ContainerInterface $container is missing when the controller is being initiated. But how do i do this? Confused.

Cheers!
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example you should inject dependencies via the controller `create` method, pass the container there, and return an array. The first item in the array is the service you’re passing to the constructor.

Then, add a constructor that expects this object as an argument, and then set `$this->membership` to the container object you passed as an argument. This should also be a protected member of the class.

But to see your example actually work first, remove the container from the test method and remove the line about `$memebrship`. Clear cache and hit that route to see Hello world!

Here is a similar question demonstrating this: [How do I use dependency injection on \Drupal::moduleHandler() to a Controller?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/226997/57)

Comment: but what is the difference between create() and __construct()?

Comment: create passes the arguments to the constructor when the class is instantiated.