# How to inject User class as dependency?

Tags: 8

How to do I inject Drupal\user\Entity\User class as dependency? I could not find service name in service list.
 for example:

```
$user = User::load($this->currentUser->id())
```

for this code I want to call like this

```
$user = $this->user->load(($this->currentUser->id())
```

when injecting in Controller. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to inject services in the controller, because ControllerBase already provides the services needed. So this should work:

```
$user = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load($this->currentUser()->id());
```

---

For other services not included in ControllerBase, see [How do I use dependency injection on \Drupal::moduleHandler() to a Controller?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226997/how-do-i-use-dependency-injection-on-drupalmodulehandler-to-a-controller)

Comment: is it same with Blocks?

Comment: No, this only works in a controller.