# Is it possible to invoke cron within a hook or route class?

Tags: 8, routes, cron

I'm using the Deploy suite, which requires cron to be run after a deployment is created. However, when I try to execute `\Drupal\Core\Cron::run();` from `hook_entity_create()` or from a route Class, it doesn't work. It dies after hitting `$this->accountSwitcher->switchTo(new AnonymousUserSession());`, throwing the error `Using $this when not in object context in Drupal\Core\Cron::run()`.

Is this just simply not possible? Is there a way around these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get that error is because `run` is not expected to be called statically. `\Drupal\Core\Cron` is a service class managed by Drupal, [registered in `core.services.yml`](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core/core.services.yml#L349). To get a reference to the instance of this service, you'll need to [inject the dependency to your controller](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/226997/57572).

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\CronInterface;

class MyController extends ControllerBase {

  protected $cron;

  public function __construct(CronInterface $cron) {
    $this->cron = $cron;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('cron')
    );  
  }

  public function myPage() {
    $this->cron->run();
  }
```

To call it from a hook, if you'll need to use `\Drupal::service()` to get a reference to the instance:

```
$cron = \Drupal::service('cron');
$cron->run();
```

A full example of how to manually run cron can be found in [the implementation of the Cron settings page](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core/modules/system/src/Form/CronForm.php) (Configure -> System -> Cron). In that page, you have a button to manually run the cron. See the `runCron` method, which is attached as the submit handler of the "Run cron" button.

Comment: Thank you, incredibly helpful. Forgot that services existed!