# What is the right way of loading a service?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection, symfony-services

when trying to use a service in drupal actually there is 3 ways , what is the preferred way to use a service and why :

1. passing dependencies directly through the constructor:

   ```
   public function __construct(AccountProxyInterface $current_user) {

   }
   ```
2. passing the dependencies through the `create()` method wich look to me the same as injecting it through the `__construct()`, with the only difference , an instance will be created eah time (no singleton design pattern - not same instance will be reused)

```
      public static function create(ContainerInterface $container)
  {
    //1.getting service from the service container.
    $Door = $container->get('custom_service.door');
    //2.create a new object of current class, and Inject the dependency  object into the constructor
    return new static($Door);
  }

  //constructor receive the dependency set by the create() method
  public function __construct(Door $Door)
  {
    kint($Door);
  }
```

3. just get get the service from the service container and no need to inject it using :

   ```
   $Door = \Drupal::service('custom_service.door')
   ```

Comment: You should always inject your arguments and typehint them to their interface counterpart whenever possible. Assigning instance variables from the global container is not advised. `\Drupal::service...` is largely used from procedural code when not in an OOP context.

Comment: 2. also has a specific context in Drupal, it is a factory method pattern used to instantiate controllers and plugins. So there is no preferred way, each one is used in a different context.

Comment: @4k4 can you explain the diffent contexts, so that I know when to use create factory method and when to inject directly into the constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The standard way to inject services in other services is passing dependencies directly through the constructor:

   *mymodule.services.yml:*

   ```
   services:
     mymodule.foo_service:
       class: Drupal\mymodule\FooService
       arguments: ['@current_user']
   ```
2. While you can define a factory method in *.services.yml, see 
   https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html,
   in Drupal the most common places for this are Controllers and Plugins which implement [ContainerInjectionInterface::create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DependencyInjection%21ContainerInjectionInterface.php/function/ContainerInjectionInterface%3A%3Acreate/8.8.x) or [ContainerFactoryPluginInterface::create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Plugin%21ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.php/function/ContainerFactoryPluginInterface%3A%3Acreate/8.8.x). See [How do I use dependency injection on \Drupal::moduleHandler() to a Controller?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226997/how-do-i-use-dependency-injection-on-drupalmodulehandler-to-a-controller)
3. `\Drupal::service...` is largely used from procedural code when not in an OOP context, like hooks or static callbacks. See the [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/290187/what-is-the-right-way-of-loading-a-service/290198#comment363333_290187) from @Kevin.

Comment: Also worth metion that you can inject dependencies (services or parameters) to a class that is not a service and will be used on procedural code like hooks by making your class implement `\Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface` and by calling it in your hook using `$instance = \Drupal::classResolver('\Drupal\my_module\MyAwesomeClass');`. Is not a service but will use services though.

Comment: Is the [linked question 226997](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226997/how-do-i-use-dependency-injection-on-drupalmodulehandler-to-a-controller) still a recommended pattern? According to [this blog post](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/safely-extending-drupal-8-plugin-classes-without-fear-of-constructor-changes) the constructor should be considered internal and subject to changes.

Comment: @Hudri, this is a good point, although it's not that you shouldn't use the design pattern anymore, it's about how you can extend existing controllers which are built with this design pattern.

Comment: For my own understanding: If I'm writing my own standalone class -> `__construct(Services...)` OK. As soon as I'm extending from another class like e.g. `ControllerBase` or `PluginBase` -> better leave the constructor alone and `$container->get()` the service inside `create()`?

Comment: No, the linked blog post is not about writing a new controller or plugin by extending a base class in your own module, it's about extending existing core/contrib controllers and plugins.