# How can I mock a service?

Tags: 8, testing

i have this code:

```
/**
 * Defines a wrapper target around a paragraph bundle's target field.
 *
 * @FeedsTarget(
 *   id = "feeds_para_mapper_temp_target",
 *   field_types = {
 *     "entity_reference_revisions",
 *   },
 *   arguments = {
 *     "@entity.manager",
 *     "@entity_field.manager"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class TempTarget extends FieldTargetBase implements, ConfigurableTargetInterface,
{
  protected $entity_type_manager;
  protected $field_manager;
  public function __construct(array $conf, $id, array $def, EntityTypeManagerInterface $en_man, EntityFieldManagerInterface $f_man)
  {
    parent::__construct($conf, $id, $def);
    $this->entity_type_manager = $en_man;
    $this->field_manager = $f_man;
  }
  // Here is where i need the instance, and it's weird because it gets called 
  // without instantiating this class:
  public function defaultConfiguration(){
    // This function create a form configuration and return it:
    $definition = $this->targetDefinition;
    $field = $definition->getFieldDefinition();
    $instance = $this->createTargetInstance($field,$this->feedType)
  }
  // Calls this plugin manager to get instance of another plugin
  public function createTargetInstance(FieldConfigInterface $field, FeedTypeInterface $feed_type){
    // This is where the test is failing:
    $manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.feeds.target');
  }
}
```

what it does it calls a plugin manager in order to create instance definition,
whenever it gets tested i see this error:

```
\Drupal::$container is not initialized yet.
```

which i know is caused by calling to the service
i have tried this in the test file:

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$manager = $this->prophesize('Drupal\feeds\Plugin\Type\FeedsPluginManager');
$container->set('plugin.manager.feeds.target', $manager);
\Drupal::setContainer($container);
```

Not working.
i tried as the answer suggested in the comment bellow to add implement `ContainerInjectionInterface` not working, and with `ContainerFactoryPluginInterface` as [this article](https://chromatichq.com/blog/dependency-injection-drupal-8-plugins) suggested, not working too, in both implementations the `create()` method is never get called
i tried to add this to he annotation:

```
 *   arguments = {
 *     "@entity.manager",
 *     "@entity_field.manager",
 *     "@plugin.manager.feeds.target"
 *   }
```

with this constructor:

```
public function __construct(array $$conf, $id, array $def, EntityTypeManagerInterface $en_m, EntityFieldManagerInterface $f_m, FeedsPluginManager $p_m)
  {
    $stop = null;
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->entity_type_manager = $en_m;
    $this->field_manager = $f_m;
    $this->plugin_manager = $p_m;
  }
```

and it's working only if this class is instantiated, and as i said it's not when the `defaultCongiguration()` get called, i can go without the plugin manager at this stage but i really prefer if i can have it in this function.

## Update:

The reason why implementing either `ContainerInjectionInterface` or `ContainerFactoryPluginInterface` didn't work is because i added my dependencies in the `arguments`, annotation and in the `create()` method too.

Comment: I don't see the entire class but shouldn't that be passed in instead of called statically?

Comment: no the test is failing with this exception `Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerNotInitializedException`: i think a plugin manager is some kind of service: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/creating-your-own-plugin-manager

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Drupal calls should be avoided in classes, use dependency injection instead"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207151/drupal-calls-should-be-avoided-in-classes-use-dependency-injection-instead)

Comment: I was confused why this was a duplicate at first, but to explain, I think that leymannx is suggesting you can work around your question by by injecting FeedsPluginManager into the static method. Then it can be mocked without creating a container. I see how this could be a duplicate given that.

Comment: it is not duplicate, and i already tried it and not working there is something worked for me but only if the constructor got called, but wait you said injecting into static method, is there such thing ??

Comment: i've updated my question, any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a unit test (not mentioned in the OP). If so, the intention should be to test the methods of the `TempTarget` class, which means, that the first thing needed would be to instantiate an instance of that class, e.g.

```
/**
 * Instantiates and returns a TempTarget object.
 */
protected function getTempTargetInstance()
{
  $id = $this->generateId();
  $def = $this->generateDef();
  // This is where you mock the constructor dependencies/services.
  // You probably will need to create a mock like this:
  //   $this->getMockBuilder('Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager')
  //     ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  //     ->getMock();
  $this->entityTypeManager = $this->getEntityTypeManagerMock();
  $this->entityFieldManager = $this->getEntityFieldManagerMock();

  // You can now call the constructor.
  $tempTarget = new TempTarget($id, $def, $this->entityTypeManager, $this->entityFieldManager);
  return $tempTarget;
}
```

At this point, your object should be instantiated and you can call methods on it to assert the assumptions you want to be testing. For example:

```
public function testDefaultConfigurationMethod()
{
  $tempTarget = $this->getTempTargetInstance();
  $formConfiguration = $tempTarget->defaultConfiguration();
  // Test different assertions given the $formConfiguration object.  
}
```

However, at the time you call `defaultConfiguration()` you know that you need a container available that holds an entry for `plugin.manager.feeds.target`, so, you have to have that prepared in advance. The right place for that would be your `setUp()` method in your class, for example:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setUp() {
  parent::setUp();

  // Provide a mock service container, for the services our module uses.
  $container = new ContainerBuilder();
  $container->set('plugin.manager.feeds.target', $this->getFeedsTargetPluginManagerMock());
  \Drupal::setContainer($container);
  ...
  // Further setting-up of your testing class.
}
```

with `getFeedsTargetPluginManagerMock()` looking something like this:

```
/**
 * Creates and returns a mock for the feeds  
 */
protected function getFeedsTargetPluginManagerMock() {
  $feedsTargetPluginManager = $this
    ->getMockBuilder('Drupal\feeds\Plugin\Type\FeedsPluginManager')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
  ...
  // Further mocking of the objects methods if needed.
  ...
  return $feedsTargetPluginManager;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Sure thing, did you manage to make it work in the end?

Comment: Yes the test is working now, i had to change few things in the main code

Comment: Good to know, would be very helpful for others landing here if you could update your question with the final details.